# IE9.0 and colgroup / colspam issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer

IE 9.0 does not render following HTML correctly and I am out of ideas......
Please help.
**I CANNOT change     "< !DOCTYPE html >". any ideas ?**
Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<table style="table-layout:fixed;" width="100%" border="1">
    <colgroup span="120">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="120">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="15">aa</td>
            <td colspan="15">ss</td>
            <td colspan="90">dd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="120">zzzzzzzz</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Colspan = number of columns to combine into a single cell. I am affraid you use it to set width of a column. And that's wrong. Use CSS width property to set width of a column.

`<td width="120" colspan="3">`

(that was plain HTML) or with CSS

`<td style="width:120px" colspan="3">`

Answer (score 0):

The markup violates the HTML table mode, as the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) would tell you, in its somewhat cryptic way. The `colspan` attribute specifies the number of table columns that a cell spans. You cannot span 120 columns when there are only 3 columns.

It seems to me that what you really want is to divide the available width between the columns so that the relations are 15 : 15 : 90. Simplify this to 1 : 1 : 6 and then turn them to percentages:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;" width="100%" border="1">
     <col width="12.5%">
     <col width="12.5%">
     <col width="75%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aa</td>
            <td>ss</td>
            <td>dd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">zzzzzzzz</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Using fixed layout, the widths of columns are determined when the first row is processed. Therefore, the widths need to be set in `col` elements. Otherwise, the browser, when processing the first row, would not have any width requirements, so it would, by the specs, divide the total space evenly between the columns.