# Why does Internet Explorer 9/10 ignore column widths when using colspan?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I guess the following code shall explain the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
body { padding-bottom: 24px }
table { table-layout: fixed }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table class="question" id="TR09_tab" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<colgroup>
  <col width="22">
  <col width="110">
  <col>
</colgroup>
<tr>
  <td><input name="one" id="one" value="yes" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td colspan="2"><label for="one">Option 1</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name="two" id="two" value="yes" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td colspan="2"><label for="two">Option 2</label></td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none">
  <td colspan="2"><label for="text">Text:</label></td>
  <td><input name="text" id="text" type="text" value="" style="width: 98%"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem: The first colum is rendered much larger than 22px.

Note: I cannot use a fixed width for the table, because there's a variable-width-layout underlying the table.

The third row is set display:none because it shall be shown (via JavaScript) as soon as one of the options is chosen. As soon as this row is shown, all the col-widths are perfectly correct.

I already faced problems with col-width-definitions and IE when using colspan in other contexts - however this is the first time, that the width for a non-spanned cell is ignored.

- Why does IE 9/10 simply ignore my colgroup definitions in this case?
- Any suggestions to solve the problem *if* I cannot change the table
  structure (i.e., I need these three colums and the colspans)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522196/ie9-0-and-colgroup-colspam-issue

Comment: Even if I remove the last row, the W3C validator does not report any error. Further, the code in the other post does *not* define any column widths. I may be simply blind, but I do not get the point?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that IE gets confused with the table structure when you have `display: none` on the last row. If you remove that setting, the widths change. Without that row, the table violates the HTML table model (as the validator reports, if you actually remove the row from the markup and tell the validator to do HTML5 validation, where table model errors are detected).

Things change if you replace `display: none` by `visibility: collapse`, though that setting is not supported by some old versions of IE.

Foremost, I think the table structure should be correct when visible rows only are counted.

Comment: Again, I tested the code *without* the last row at http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and it gives me a "Valid" (although there are two warnings for the missing character encoding). Anyway thank you for the hint on "visibility" - this immediately solves the problem :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that the validator reports the problem *if in HTML5 mode*. The HTML table model requirements cannot be expressed in DTDs, so they are reported in HTML5 validation only. I’ll edit my answer.