# Fixed table column width (using colgroup) not working after removing column in IE and Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I have a table with markup as shown

```
<table>
<colgroup>
<col span="1" width="120px" />
<col span="1" width="230px" />
<col span="1" width="230px" />
<col span="1" width="230px" />
</colgroup>
<thead>...</thead>
<tbody>...</tbody>
</table>
```

The columns have fixed width (as I want) in every browser. But when I delete a particular column (using jQuery - part of functionality) the colgroup's col width is maintained in Chrome and Firefox but not in Internet Explorer and Safari.

jQuery to delete a particular column:

```
function deleteshift(obj){
    var tdindex = obj.parent().index() - 1 ;
    var thindex = obj.parent().index();

    $(obj).closest('table').find('tr').find('td:eq('+ tdindex +'),th:eq('+ thindex +')').fadeOut(500,function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

}
```

I have tried every possible solution - from assign width to td's and th's, to removing columns instead of hiding, visibility - collapse etc but nothing seems to work.

Check this out : [Why does Internet Explorer 9/10 ignore column widths when using colspan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177089/why-does-internet-explorer-9-10-ignore-column-widths-when-using-colspan)

Comment: Works just the same in IE and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/3fyLN/

Comment: Thnks for the fiddle...but the width of the cells is changing after clicking the del...width of 3rd column was 150 initially and after clicking del it is 187 px...i want them to have same width even after clicking del..

Comment: @bhavyaw: Added as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the columns are given a fixed width, but the table layout is not. If the table layout is not `fixed`, the columns will grow to fill the remainder from the last.

You need to provide `table-layout: fixed` to the table in order to honour the widths.

***Demo***: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/3fyLN/3/

*HTML*:

```
<table id="tab">
    <colgroup>
        <col span="1" width="100" />
        <col span="1" width="150" />
        <col span="1" width="150" />
        <col span="1" width="100" />
        </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            ....
```

*CSS*:

```
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table {
    width: 500px;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

*Important*: If you remove any of the columns, the next column will pick up the `colgroup` width as the column index would now shift to the next one. i.e. when you remove the 3rd column, then the 4th one would take its index position and hence the width that was applied to that index would apply.

*Note*: It is better to specify width thru CSS instead of as an attribute.

**Update**:

In fact if the table `width` is set to `auto`, then it is IE which behaves the way it should. Chrome expands the columns!

*Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/3fyLN/5/*

And if, the whole colgroup is removed and widths specified on the columns in first row only, then it works just fine in both IE and Chrome.

*Demo 3: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/3fyLN/6/*

Comment: Thanks again...Firstly table-layout:fixed is already there in my css( not shared here).The Fiddle you just gave me is working in the exact same manner my application is working. I.E its preserving the columns width in chrome and firefox but its not preserving the width in I.e and safari. Have you tried it in I.E . After clicking remove 2 3 times when only one column is left. its width increases to the table width.( it remains preserved in chrome) . I dont want it to loose its initial width specified through colgroup.

Comment: Hmmmm... yes, I did observe it closely enough! In fact, IE is doing it right, Chrome isn't. Have added the second demo above.

Comment: Also see the third demo above with a workaround which works in both IE and Chrome.

Comment: thanks a lot...Table width:auto added the missing ingredient.

Answer (score 2):

```
<col span="1" width="120px" />
```

The width attribute should not have any units (px).

This attribute is also not available in HTML5, use css instead.

Comment: I have already done it using CSS. The thing is its working fine before hiding the column but not after it.